# Zend Framework: Form: Should I use camelCase for form element names & DB tables, or not?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I like everything to be neat and semantic, therefore I am reaching out for some advice on a subject I am 50/50 on, I realise this is pretty much down to personal preference but want to stick to doing things one way.

Note: I know this question has been asked before, but the answers are very mixed and usually boil down to... stick to the convention being used in the application. But when creating a new application, whats the best way to do it?

**The database columns look like:**

description, user_id, blah_id

**Therefore should my form elements look like:**

Option 1:  $userId = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('**user_id**');

**OR**

option 2:  $userId = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('**userId**');

**OR:**

Change the (MySQL) database to include camelCase tables and columns too??

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I have decided the best way to go generally for my applications are, form elements and database fields camelCase and database tables to use underscores _ due to lack of support for camelCase table names with hosting companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework use camelCase. So if you can change the naming of tables and column, use this.